# Changing the Twitter Bootstrap stock Navbar to Transparent

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, background-color, transparent, navbar

I've seen a number of questions and answers about changing the background color of the default Twitter Bootstrap Primary Navbar, but they seem to deal with the top-most layer (the navbar-inner class), masking a number of other colors and options underneath.

I'm looking to create a transparent navbar, and after adding "background-color:transparent;" to each layer I can find, I still have a stock white bar across the top of my screen. Currently my app.css has these few lines:

```
.navbar-inner{
    background-color:transparent;
    }
.navbar-inner container{
    background-color:transparent;
    }
.navbar{
    background-color:transparent;
    }
#nav-main{
    background-color:transparent;
    }
#banner{
    background-color:transparent;
    }
```

I'm running out of guesses here, and my scatter-shot method seems to be failing me. Is there a rule I just haven't seen (and modified) yet, or am I going about this the wrong way altogether?

Comment: Can you please post your html or a jsFiddle example please?

Comment: Any idea how this Transparent container was set?  The menu bar at : http://www.automatic.com/

Comment: possible duplicate of [css to make bootstrap navbar transparent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16392952/css-to-make-bootstrap-navbar-transparent)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is they are using an image on the background.  So by setting the background-color, you are only setting the color behind the image.  Try something along these lines:

```
    .navbar-inner{
    background:transparent !important;
    }
.navbar-inner container{
    background:transparent !important;
    }
.navbar{
    background:transparent !important;
    }
#nav-main{
    background:transparent !important;
    }
#banner{
    background:transparent !important;
    }​
```

Answer (score 0):

Got this result in Bootstrap 3 using:

```
body { background: transparent }
```

Comment: of course, this assumes you want the whole body to default to transparent to your background image.