# css to make bootstrap navbar transparent

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I use bootstrap and I have a navbar in my html file I would like to make this nav bar transparent to show the background image. Can some one teach me how to do this with css? I tried the following css nothing happend

```
.navbar-inner {
    background-color:transparent;
}

<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="navbar-inner">
                    <div class="container">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        </button>
                        <a class="brand" href="#">lol</a>
                        <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
                            <ul class="nav pull-right">
                                <li class="active"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                                <li><a href="about">About</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Please post the links or jsfiddle link

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I was able to make the navigation bar transparent by adding a new .transparent class to the .navbar and setting the CSS like this:

```
 .navbar.transparent.navbar-inverse .navbar-inner {
    border-width: 0px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.0);
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 50.00% 0.00%, 50.00% 100.00%, color-stop( 0% , rgba(0,0,0,0.00)),color-stop( 100% , rgba(0,0,0,0.00)));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(270deg,rgba(0,0,0,0.00) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.00) 100%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(180deg,rgba(0,0,0,0.00) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.00) 100%);
}
```

My markup is like this

```
<div class="navbar transparent navbar-inverse">
            <div class="navbar-inner">....
```

Comment: thanks... using your code with `Bootstrap 4` and its works like charm :)

Comment: This is only relevant for Bootstrap 3 when the question was asked. For Bootstrap 4 is not needed since the Navbar already is transparent

Answer (score 73):

> Simply add this to your css :-

```
.navbar-inner {
    background:transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 56):

What you people are doing is unnecessary.

For transparent background, simply do:

```html
<div class="navbar">
// your navbar content
</div>
```

without class navbar-default or navbar-inverse.

Comment: This would work for a plan `nav` element, however the default styling with the Bootstrap framework includes a background gradient, which the OP is looking to remove.

Answer (score 19):

If you are using the latest version of Bootstrap and Ruby on Rails, you can just type it in the html.erb file as so:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-transparent">
```

And that is all you need.

Answer (score 18):

***Update 2019***

**Bootstrap 4 - The Navbar is transparent by default**

Most of the answers here are misleading because they relate to Bootstrap 3. **By default, the Bootstrap 4 Navbar is transparent**. Just remember to use `navbar-light` or `navbar-dark` so the link colors work against the contrast of the background color...

https://www.codeply.com/go/FTDyj4KZlQ

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm fixed-top navbar-light">
    <div class="container">
        <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar1">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar1">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: I dont want to have a transparent navbar and I'm using bootstrap 4. what should I do?

Answer (score 8):

**There is no need for all this mess.**

> You can make the navbar transparent by not writing `navbar-default`or
>   `navbar-inverse`

```
<nav class="navbar">  //Don't add navbar-default to the class

  //

</nav>
```

Answer (score 5):

Add the bg-transparent class to the navbar.

```
<div class="bg-primary">
    <div class="navbar navbar-dark bg-transparent">
         ...
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

CSS code:

```
.header .navbar-default {
  background: none;
}
```

HTML code:

```
<header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default"></nav>
</header>
```

Answer (score 3):

in bootstrap 3.3.7 (and 4.0 presumably), this works:

instead of:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
```

use:

```
<nav class="navbar bg-transparent navbar-fixed-top">
```

no CSS required!

Answer (score 2):

Just leaving the default navbar built in with bootstrap works fine.
You just need to add the custom css below, that way everything still works as it should.

HTML:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
```

CSS:

```
.navbar-default {
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this in your code, it worked for me -

give an id to the element, to which you want to make transparent

for eg according to your code -

```
<div class="navbar-inner" id="nav1">
```

Then apply this in your css-

```
#nav1
{  
    background-color:#F00;  /*whichever you want*/
    opacity: 0.5;           /*0.5 determines transparency value*/ 
    filter:(opacity=50);       
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This works for 4.0.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm fixed-top navbar-light">
or
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg fixed-top navbar-dark">
```

key item is ***fixed-top***, otherwise, white or default page background is displayed even if there is a image top.
***navbar-light*** gives dark letters, ***navbar-dark*** shows light text.

Answer (score 1):

Further to Jochem Stoel's answer... I added 'navbar-fixed-top' to the DIV tag's class and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-light" style="background-color: transparent;">

<!--This should work just fine. it will make it transparent. hope i helped!-->
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Test with `background-image: none`. That property will remove the `linear-gradient`.

You can see the result here: http://jsfiddle.net/eugip9/8D36M/

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the latest version of `Bootstrap` i.e `4.0.0` you just need to use the 'transparent' keyword as:

`<nav class="navbar navbar-light transparent">`

There is simply no need to apply any css for this as bootstrap has this property inbuilt.

Answer (score 0):

For **Spring** + **Thymeleaf** (*boostrap*) project i usually use:

Inside css the following code

```
.navbar-inner {
        background:transparent;
    }
```

Inside the HTML the line

```
<nav class="navbar-inner">
```

Answer (score 0):

One workaround it to give the navbar container a "fixed-top" class and than change the fixed-top styles to "position: absolute";

Here is the code:

```
    <header class="nav-wrapper">
      <div class="container fixed-top">
        <nav class="navbar">
        </nav>
      </div>
    </header>
```

```
.fixed-top {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1030;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light fixed-top bg-transparent">
              <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar w/ text</a>
              <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarText" aria-controls="navbarText" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
              </button>
              <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarText">
                <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                  <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
                <span class="navbar-text">
                  Navbar text with an inline element
                </span>
              </div>
            </nav>
```

Comment: could you please provide some more context to your answer, what it does? why it works? so others could learn from that. Please consider to check [answer]

Comment: This is the code of a transparent bootstrap navigation bar. You can simply copy paste my code and enjoy. Above mentioned answers were not helpful for me and people who are facing same problem can try this code.

Answer (score 0):

just add
**background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255, 0);**

to your navbar class