# How to make a navbar transparent?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

This is the HTML code for navigation bar using Bootstrap framework.
I want to make it little transparent.

How to do this with CSS? I tried but nothing happend.

```
<nav role="navigation" class="navbar navbar-default">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" data-target="#navbarCollapse" data-toggle="collapse" class="navbar-toggle">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a href="#" class="navbar-brand"></a>
    </div>
    <!-- Collection of nav links and other content for toggling -->
    <div id="navbarCollapse" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav" style="margin-left:10%">
            <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">ABOUT US</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">HEALTH MANAGEMENT</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">PRE-POST PRAGNANCY</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">WEIGHT LOSS</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">CONTACT US</a></li>

        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="#"></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Post the CSS you have for the nav.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [css to make bootstrap navbar transparent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16392952/css-to-make-bootstrap-navbar-transparent)

Comment: Are you using a css Preprocessor? if you are using less/sass just replace the variable  `@navbar-default-bg`

eg: `@navbar-default-bg: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)`

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your CSS

```
.navbar-header {
    background:transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `rgba` color.

**E.g.:**

```
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't post the css. Though, if you want to change the background color of the nav you need to use RGBA color. So, you can make your nav bar little transparent with white background this way -

```
.navbar-default{
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Give your `nav` an ID so it's easy to select with CSS.

Then just use

```
#yourNavsID { opacity:0.7; }
```

Obviously you can change the 0.7 to whatever number suits your needs.

Example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fr2wayy7/