# How to make a Bootstrap Navigation Bar transparent

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to make my navigation bar transparent which I made using bootstrap. I have tried previous solutions of stackoverflow but none of them worked. this is my code:

```
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
   <a class="navbar-brand mb-0 h1" href="#">Navbar </a>
   <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarText" 
       aria-controls="navbarText" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
   </button>
   <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarText">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
   </div>
   <div class="aa">
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
   <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
   <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
 </form>
  </div>
  <div class="">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
   <li class="nav-link"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Login</a></li>
  </ul>
 </div>
 </nav>
```

I have tried this [css to make bootstrap navbar transparent](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16392952/10976122) but it does not work for me.

Comment: You have not required a class in your navbar which given in the referenced answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is it:
 just add this in the head section below all link tags:

```
<style>
        .navbar {
            position: relative;
            display: -ms-flexbox;
            display: flex;
            -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
            -ms-flex-align: center;
            align-items: center;
            -ms-flex-pack: justify;
            justify-content: space-between;
            padding: .5rem 1rem;
            opacity: 0.5;
        }
    </style>
```

check : https://jsfiddle.net/sugandhnikhil/32kuLbmd/

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Use class bg-transparent instead of bg-light

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-transparent">
   <a class="navbar-brand mb-0 h1" href="#">Navbar </a>
   <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarText" 
       aria-controls="navbarText" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
   </button>
   <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarText">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
   </div>
   <div class="aa">
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
   <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
   <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
 </form>
  </div>
  <div class="">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
   <li class="nav-link"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Login</a></li>
  </ul>
 </div>
 </nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using a class" bg-light", you need to remove this in order to make the transparent navbar.

```css
body {
  background-image: url(https://www.blackhillsbadlands.com/sites/default/files/styles/bhb40_page_hero/public/photos/events/5th-annual-holiday-bazaar/abstract-background-blur-255377.jpg?itok=TBiKp5V6);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<body>


  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
    <a class="navbar-brand mb-0 h1" href="#">Navbar </a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarText" aria-controls="navbarText" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
<span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
   </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarText">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="aa">
      <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
        <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div class="">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="nav-link"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Login</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</body>
```