# Transparent Nav Bar with bootstrap not working as desired

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6GqvD.png)

I am trying to make my navbar transparent but as you can see from the image the color is not the same throughout the navbar. The content is slightly darker than the surrounding area. It seems as though it is applying the transparency twice to make one portion slightly darker. I have included the bootstrap override I am using.

```
#bootstrap-overrides .bg-dark {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6) !important;
}
```

Comment: Please post your HTML and CSS as well.

Comment: How many times are you applying the `bg-dark` class? It seems that there is one time for the outer element and one more for the inner (slightly darker) element.

Answer (score 0):

You probably used the class bg-dark both in your `navbar div` and near the `ul` containing your links.
In this case, only use it in your `navbar div` and it will works !

Maybe you can post your html for checking ?

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using css, add the class below using bootstrap :

`<nav class="navbar bg-transparent nav-dark"></nav>`

The **bg-transparent** will make what you want; don't forget to delete your css

Comment: This does nothing as the Navbar is transparent by default

Comment: Are you sure? I've done it and it was succesfully done.

Comment: Codeply-er I think if you give !important to styles, still bootstrap does its work and when pzero1 adds **bg-dark** class background becomes dark.

Comment: the `.navbar` has NO background-color unless you explicitly give it one, or use one of the `bg-*` classes. Therefore there is no reason to use `bg-transparent`. see [this](https://codeply.com/p/EFTKHSB0GZ) or https://stackoverflow.com/a/49258102/171456