# My bootstrap navbar is white? However I want to have a transparent Navbar

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Can someone please help me find the solution as to why I can't change my Navbar to transparent?

My bootstrap navbar is white but I want it to be transparent - I want my navbar to be the color of my banner image which is underneath it. But even if I use !important it still remains white? Please help me get rid of the Navbar background color.

My Navbar

[image]

My HTML

```
<header id="header">
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg px-4">
    <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">
    <img src="img/logo4.png" alt="main icon">
    </a>
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="toggler-icon">
        <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
        </span>
        </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
        <ul class="navbar-nav text-capitalize mx-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active">
            <a href="#header" class="nav-link"> home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item active">
            <a href="#about" class="nav-link"> about</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item active">
            <a href="#store" class="nav-link"> store</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item active">
            <a href="#footer-title" class="nav-link"> contact</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        
        <div class="nav-info-items d-none d-lg-flex">
            <!-- phone number -->
            <div class="nav-info align-items-center d-flex justify-content-between mx-lg-5">
                <span class="info-icon mx-lg-3">
                <i class="fas fa-phone"></i>
                </span>
                <p class="mb-0">+ 27 (84) 836 1281 </p>
            </div>
            <!--  end of phone number   -->
<!-- cart -->
            <div id="cart-info" class="nav-info align-items-center cart-info d-flex justify-content- 
   between mx-lg-5">
            <span class="cart-info_icon mr-lg-3">
                <i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i>
                </span>
                <p class="mb-0 text-capitalize">cart</p>
                
                
            </div>
            
        </div>
    </div>
    </nav>
```

My style

```
.navbar {
background-image:none !important;
background-color: transparent !important;
}

/* nav links */
.navbar-toggler{
outline: none !important;
}

.toggler-icon {
font-size: 2.5rem;
color: var(--mainPink);
}
.nav-link{
color: var(--mainPink);
transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
font-size: 1rem;
}
.nav-link:hover{
color: var(--mainBlack);
}
```

Comment: Open DevTools in Chrome and investigate first which elements paints the white background. Then you can target it with css and set it explizit to transparent.

Comment: The Bootstrap [navbar is already transparent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49258102/171456). You must have other CSS that is effecting the background color.

Answer (score 0):

use opacity effect or background rgba in your navbar

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a job for the DOM Inspector/Developer Toolkit/whatever it is called in your browser.

Instead of checking your code in conjunction with bootstraps default styles, I'll write up a generic way to find the element with the white background by yourself.

First, you need to know the "inspect element" feature (available in at least Chrome and Firefox). Right-clicking any page element (e.g. your navbar) should give you an option like "Inspect" or "Inspect element". Use this. The developer console will open and highlight the frontmost element from the element stack you clicked on in the HTML view. (Alternatively, you may press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>I</kbd> or <kbd>F12</kbd>, then use the arrow icon in the top left corner of the developer console to select an element.)

Second, if an element is highlighted, the "Rules" or "Styles" tab of the developer console will show you all rules that apply to this element. There also is a "Computed" tab that will show you the end result of all rules applying to that element. Between those tabs, check whether any background rule is set to something non-transparent.

Third, if you did not find the background rule that made your navbar white, check the same for any parent elements—the background may be set for an outer div or header; it just may happen that they are the same size! Hovering over an element in the HTML view will also highlight that element in the page: that way, you can find all the elements of the same size as your navbar.

Once you found the element, switch back to the "rules" tab: There you can edit CSS on the fly, just to try out which rule would help you there.

This may not be enough yet: It may be that your header (incl navbar) pushes the content down; and the background image you want to show under the navbar might only apply to the content div. In this case, you might need to apply that background image to the body instead of the content—use the rules tab again to apply a background color (I prefer using a really garish color that would not show up anywhere in the color scheme of the page) to the body element and have a look where it shines through.

Do not forget that changing the rules on the fly isn't persistent—when you reload or navigate away from a page, all on-the-fly changes are lost. I recommend to play around often with the developer console, just to get a feel for using it—it is an invaluable tool to answer questions like you posed, but needs a bit of learning and fiddling to interpret it correctly.

Comment: Thanks for your help very insightful. Nothing seems to be working though - I've tried all your suggestions . The Navbar seems to be responding to the style                              
  body {
  background: var(--mainWhite);
}  it changes different colors but wont respond to transparent or opacity

Comment: @Kate In this case, it seems like the "banner image which is underneath it" that you mentioned isn't really underneath it; or does not match the size of the navbar; or it's parent element has a height of zero; or something like that. You may try and locate the element that should contain/display your banner image to see whether this one works and has the right size and position (just hover over the HTML tag of that element to see its size and position highlighted).

Comment: @Kate The "Network" tab of the developer console also shows you all resources that have been loaded for your page (you may need to reload with that tab open) -- status 200 is "OK", a status of 400-something shows a problem with loading a file (e.g. your banner image). It just may be that your banner image isn't being loaded (I cannot see from your question whether your "banner image" is different from the page background image). I'm probably not telling you something new here, but in web development, it is a difference whether a filename is written in upper- or lowercase characters.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg px-4" style="background-color: transparent">
```

Answer (score -1):

change your css to :

```
.navbar {
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0);
}
```

which means :
set background color to black and opacity to 0% == transparent

Ref :
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_colors.asp